# Spritekit bodyWithbodies does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want my `spritenode` to have multiple `physicbodies`. I used `bodyWithbodies` and added the `phyisicbodies`. But no collision is detected.

Below the method for creating the `spritenode` which should have more `physicbodies`.

```
-(void)spawnBrick
{
    SKPhysicsBody *brickLeftEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width - brick.size.width, brick.size.height - brick.size.height) toPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width - brick.size.width, brick.size.height)];
    brickLeftEdge.categoryBitMask = brickLeftEdgeCategory;
    brickLeftEdge.contactTestBitMask = leftEdgeCategory;

SKPhysicsBody *brickRightEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width, brick.size.height - brick.size.height) toPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width, brick.size.height)];
brickRightEdge.categoryBitMask = brickRightEdgeCategory;
brickRightEdge.contactTestBitMask = rightEdgeCategory;

brick = [[BrickNodeOne alloc] init];
brick.name = @"Brick";

NSArray *array = [self objectForKeyedSubscript:@"Brick"];
BrickNodeOne *oldBrick;
if ([array count] > 0) {
    oldBrick = [array objectAtIndex:([array count]-1)];
}
brick.position = CGPointMake(brick.size.width / 2, (brick.size.height + oldBrick.position.y)-15);
brick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[brickLeftEdge, brickRightEdge]];

    brick.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    [self addChild:brick];
}
```

In `DidMoveToView` I declared the left and right edge of the screen for collision detection with the `spritenode`

```
    // setup edges
_leftEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
// heigt + 1000 = for spawned objects above screen
_leftEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, self.size.height + 1000)];
_leftEdge.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
_leftEdge.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = leftEdgeCategory;
_leftEdge.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = brickLeftEdgeCategory;
_leftEdge.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:_leftEdge];

_rightEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
// heigt + 1000 = for spawned objects above screen
_rightEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(self.size.width, 0.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(self.size.width, self.size.height + 1000)];
_rightEdge.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
_rightEdge.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rightEdgeCategory;
_rightEdge.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = brickRightEdgeCategory;
[self addChild:_rightEdge];
```

The following code contains the bitmask information:

I declared `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` in the header file. Set the delegate in `didMoveToView`

```
static const uint32_t leftEdgeCategory          = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t rightEdgeCategory         = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t brickLeftEdgeCategory     = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t brickRightEdgeCategory    = 0x1 << 3;
static const uint32_t kCarCategory              = 0x1 << 4;
```

**Information for comment**

So I changed the `physicsbody` from edge to rectangle, unfortunately no contact was detected.

```
SKPhysicsBody *brickLeftEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, brick.size.height) center:CGPointMake((brick.size.width - brick.size.width) + 20 , self.size.height / 2)];
brickLeftEdge.categoryBitMask = brickLeftEdgeCategory;
brickLeftEdge.contactTestBitMask = leftEdgeCategory;

SKPhysicsBody *brickRightEdge = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, brick.size.height) center:CGPointMake(brick.size.width - 20, brick.size.height / 2)];
brickRightEdge.categoryBitMask = brickRightEdgeCategory;
brickRightEdge.contactTestBitMask = rightEdgeCategory;
```

Comment: Also the term "collision detection" is not appropriate in these kind of projects (SpriteKit projects) and may be confusing. When it comes to detection, it is more usual to say "contact detection". And when it comes to collisions, you can say that "collision should or shouldn't happen" because, you don't detect collisions, but rather contacts (didBeginContact detects contacts and there is no didBeginCollision method).

Comment: For example, you can have collisions enabled (normal physics simulation where bodies bounce of when hit each other etc.) even if contact detection is disabled (didBeginContact will not be called). Also, you can have only contact detection enabled ( didBeginContact method will be called), but collisions (realistic physics simulation) will be disabled. Or you can have them both at the same time. Still there is a difference between contacts and collisions, and there is no such a thing as "collision detection" (but rather contact detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is related to the fact that you are using static physics bodies. This is from the docs about [bodyWithEdgeFromPoint: toPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint:) method:

> An edge has no volume or mass and is always treated as if the dynamic
>   property is equal to NO. **Edges may only collide with volume-based
>   physics bodies**.

Means, collisions can happen only when at least one body is defined as dynamic (volume-based physics bodies are dynamic by default).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I switched the spritenode edges to small rectangles. It crashes, compiler tells: nothing is added to the array (bodywithbodies). Is the way I use bodyWithbodies right?

Comment: @Nielsapp Update your original question with a code which can reproduce what you are saying. I can't comment something that I don't see :) Or ask another question if the issue differs from your original question, or editing will make a mess :)  Also, check for typos and other silly errors...

Comment: I edited my question for clarification below. I think this is on topic, because this question is related to the problem (bodyWithBodies) which is not working yet.

Comment: @Nielsapp So what was the issue again ? Those bodies are nil or ?

Comment: I solved that problem, it doesn't crash anymore. Only no contact is detected.

Comment: @Nielsapp Well if the contact will end up detected depends mainly on three things. First, did you set `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` ? Second, do you handle contacts properly inside `didBeginContact` method? And third is how you set category and contact bit masks between bodies you want to register contacts. Of course, as I said in my answer, at least one body has to be dynamic to detect the contact.

Comment: So it's possible for a spritenode to have multiple bitmasks assigned to it's category? For example node.physicsbody.categorybit.. = physicsbody1 | physicsbody2?